# Is there an easy way of publishing the value of a single google sheet cell into a website?

Tags: javascript

I want to publish the contents of a single google sheet cell on my website (php/html/js/css).

What would be the easiest solution to make this possible?

The contents should be shown within a normal sentence.
For example: At this moment we have (cell content) stray dogs who are looking for a new home.

Since the google sheet is a collab between different offices, this would be the easiest way to keep our website up to date.

Comment: Is the sheet readable by anyone? Depending on the answer you might be able to do it client-side or not.

Comment: I can make the sheet fully accessible. I have a very limited experience with js and php though, I can change existing scripts and snippets, but that is about as far as I can go.
So any generic scripts or pointers to an existing script that I can play around with would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could request the cell by using the public API from PHP. Just update the $sheet_id and $cell values. The advantage is that you don't need to setup an API key or install the Google Sheets API package.

```
<?php
$sheet_id = '0Auwt3KepmdoudE1iZFVFYmlQclcxbW85YzNZSTYyUHc';
$cell = 'b5';
$url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key={$sheet_id}&single=true&gid=0&range={$cell}&output=csv";
$fp = fopen($url, 'r');
$cell_value = stream_get_contents($fp);
fclose($fp);
echo $cell_value;
```

Depending on how often you need this value, I'd strongly suggest caching it. The exact details vary based on your exact setup.

You can do something similar from Javascript, but there'd be two obstacles:

- The API used above does not have the correct [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) so the browser will block the request.
- The [other API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) requires an API key. Exposing that to users is not very security-minded.

Comment: Thank you very much!!
This works perfect... I only added a variable for gid as I work with multiple sheets within a single spreadsheet (and the one giving me the data is not the first sheet)